# How to say 'to keep' in Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary

Seems like an easy question, but there doesn't seem to be an easy answer!
If I have three apples in my hands and I give you two, I could say 'I'll give you these two apples, but I will keep this one'.
What is the verb for 'to keep' in this scenario? 拥有? 保持? 留下?
All thoughts much appreciated!
Hashamyim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**留(下)** is your best bet.

Here's an example from *Oxford C-E*:

> 我留下20块钱，下剩的给你。
>   I'll keep 20 *yuan* and the rest is for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I'll give you these two apples, but I'll keep them it means:

> **保留**

'to keep' can be said that **保持 保存 维持**.

> Like
> That's why I must trust you to keep this secret 
> 那就是为什么我必须得相信你会**保守**这个秘密的原因。
>   I had to keep in with the people who mattered. 
> 我得和管事儿的人**保持**良好关系
> I wanted to keep in touch, but when I called him he gave me the brush-off. 
> 我想和他**保持**联系，但当我打电话给他时，他却不理睬我。

'to keep' is a sense of **continuity**
Its effect is to put something in a certain state

Answer (score 0):

'I have 3 apples, I'll give you two apples, I'll keep this one'.
我有三个苹果，我给你两个，一个留给我自己。